# Avoid resetting Dropwizard metrics values when deploying new API version

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, counter, dropwizard, metrics

I am researching about Dropwizard Metrics, and would like to use it in an API that runs in different EC2 instances orchestrated by a Load Balancer.

When deploying a new API version, the counters are reset, and that occurs in each API (EC2) instance. I would like to find a solution that could let me avoid losing those counters current values, and also avoid further problems with the values of the same counter in different instances, as they could go out of phase.

I am thinking about a different API that only holds Counters values, so when deploying new API versions they are not reset.

Have you ever faced the situation of working with same counters in different EC2 instances running the same API?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. So it sounds like you want to persist values on shutdown, and initialise your counters on startup. You can use that using normal DAOs and such. However, this seems wrong in terms of metrics. I am not understanding your usecase 100%, but usually you submit your metrics to a persistent storage (graphite etc) which can deal with the fact that they are reset, aggregate them and do other functions for analytics. Handling this in the application seems overkill?

Comment: @pandaadb Thanks, I am working with Elasticsearch as persistent storage, but not sure if it's easy to aggregate reset metrics from Kibana/Grafana queries. Should I try aggregation queries and avoid taking care of it in my Java code?

Comment: If you have only a limited amount of counters, then there is probably no harm initialising them. However, you usually use metrics to get the behaviour of something over time (e.g. graphite to visualize a rate change etc). Essentially, for your application it shouldn't really matter that the counters are reset. Metrics should be used very quickly and not disturb your application's behaviour. If you have to add code to initialise and shut down and generally work with your metrics, then you are probably approaching it wrong

Comment: @pandaadb Ok, thanks. Now talking about EC2 instances running the same API version with a LB before them. If one of them is restarted, while the other one keeps up, won't my ES instance receive different values of the same counter? Even when no restarting one of them, values could differ. I was wondering if some other component should organize that, maybe Kafka.

Comment: @FedericoQuintas we had metrics reported to elasticsearch too, using kibana for dashboards, and we did have problems with resets on some visualizations when picking larger time windows. Another problem for our case is that kibana works with aggregations too, so you end up with aggregations of aggregations if you don't pick the right window both on the reporter and on kibana. In the end we've decided to remove the elasticsearch reporter, send the data that based the metrics directly to it and then let kibana handle everything.

Comment: @andrepnh Thanks for your help. When you say that you're sending the data directly, you mean from Dropwizard to Elasticsearch without using ESReporter? I'm not sure if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, inside the application there's a component that collect documents until a certain time or size limit is exceeded (whichever comes first) and then sends it async and in [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html) to elasticsearch using a client

Comment: @FedericoQuintas your multiple API instances should not report the same metric. Instead, you should report by host and aggregate (or evaluate) on the receiving end (ES for example, graphite, zabbix etc). So your metric would look something like: my.metric.counter.{hostname}.count - that way a restart resets the counter of that hostname and nothing more. You can handle these cases on the receiving end since you know exactly what the 0 value means.

Comment: @andrepnh Sounds great. That component code is OpenSource?

Comment: @pandaadb Excellent, it's the kind of workaround I was looking for.

Comment: @FedericoQuintas no, it's closed source. But there's nothing really special to it, every time a document is queued it checks if it's time to upload. And it's just in memory, we don't consider those metrics worth any kind of journaling. You just have to be careful about using thread safe data structures and simple concurrency management. For example, if you don't use stuff like `AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet` when uploading, you may end up with two or more threads doing it at the same time.